# Button Pressed Animation be longer

Tags: android, animation, button, pressed

i have this button xml, when it be will pressed, the pressed image(b) would be longer to display before it goes back to normal button.

Here's my xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/a" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/b" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/b" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a" />
```

Anyone has idea on this?

For the fix. i used this.

```
closeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setPressed(true);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.setPressed(false);
                try {
            Thread.sleep(150);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
        }
            return false;  

        }
 });
```

Comment: What is your question? You want to make the animation longer?

Comment: very poor explanation . by seeing this selected all somebody can understand is that there are 3 sets of images for three different states of button . now where does animation came into picture and what exactly you mean to say by "longer", no info???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
mybutton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.setPressed(true);
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
v.setPressed(false);
 }
 }, 2000);<-- you can set for how much time the button should be in pressed state..2 seco9nds in this case
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: however, this solution will be only applicable if the button is pressed quickly. how about if the button is long pressed?

Comment: i editted my question and added solution to my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can animate state changes using `exitFadeDuration`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

This will fade in/out state changes on your selector, you can change the timing to something else.